# How do I avoid conversion of signs in a good practice way (without casting)?

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion, long-integer, unsigned, signed

I am taking an `NSInteger` (`long int`) from a method and using it as a parameter in a method, which takes an `NSUInteger` (`unsigned int`).

```
NSInteger input = [someObject someMethod];
[someOtherObject someOtherMethodWithNSUInteger: input];
```

**This isn't a great idea.** What if `input` is a negative number? How can I do this in a way that *is* a good practice? Sure, I could just go

```
[someOtherObject someOtherMethodWithNSUInteger: (NSUInteger)input];
```

But that's not a good solution because if `input` is negative, it will not bound it to zero. I could resort to it if there was no other way, but I would rather not.

**Solutions that will not work:**

Why can't I just make `someMethod` return an `NSUInteger`? Or make `someOtherMethodWithNSUInteger:` take an `NSInteger`? It's because I don't own them, they are a part of Cocoa Touch.

What about returning `nil` and using `NSError` or throwing an exception? The method that I am putting this code in conforms to a protocol, so I can't add an `(NSError**)` parameter to the method, and returning `nil` without an `NSError` explaining why seems like a bad idea because since I don't have access to `someMethod`'s or `someOtherMethod`'s source code, there would be nothing for me to even fix. And if I throw an exception, there is no way for me to catch it because this is code will be used by a closed class who made the protocol.

**How can I fix this type conversion problem?**

Comment: Why do you say `[someOtherObject someOtherMethodWithNSUInteger: (NSUInteger)input];` is not a good idea?

Comment: What does it mean to you if the first method returns a negative number? Is it an error? Should you just be bounding the value (so, setting it to zero)? You need to define the desirable outcome...

Comment: @Wain I would be bounding it.

Comment: @Merlevede because it will not bound the value to zero.

Comment: Then use something like MAX(input,0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer somewhat straightforward, and it's basically what you said yourself.

If `someOtherMethodWithNSUInteger` expects unsigned and the only thing you have is a signed value (returned from `someMethod`) then two things will happen: (1) half of the possible values expected will never be used, and (2) half of the possible values returned are invalid. No matter what method you use you will always have these issues. So the easiest thing to do is use a simple type-casting, and trim negative values to prevent them being interpreted as very large positive values.

```
[someOtherObject someOtherMethodWithNSUInteger: (NSUInteger)MAX(input,0)];
```

Comment: The method for doing NSUInteger to NSInteger would be `(NSInteger)MIN(input, INT_MAX)`, for anyone wondering.

Comment: @EthenA.Wilson Technically what you say is wrong, mainly because a **huge value would be converted to another positive value**, in 99.99% of the cases this would be disastrous.

Comment: In situations where you want it to bound to the closest number possible, it works. But in the other situations, why would you want the undefined behavior from taking a number over the `NSInteger` max and turning it into a `NSUInteger` over bounding to that?